# Hybris: How to display brand facets on storefront

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I have to use a product data that has been enhanced to store the brand in attribute "manufacturerName". The facets are the brands of the devices and next to the the facet is amount of available products (e.g.: Apple(13), HTC (6), Alcatel (2), Nokia(5), etc.). Thus the user can configure his device list by selecting the different facets.

I changed the "manufacturerName" type to string in solr.impex and after that added it as a facet

```
;$solrIndexedType; manufacturerName         ;string ;    ;     ;     ;     ;     ;MultiSelectOr ;Alpha ; 1000;true  ;     ;     ;springELValueProvider          ;
```

but in my case I have hard coded  products that should be changed with dynamic ones

```
<div class="products-list">
    <div class="product" data-filter="all">
      All (41)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="manufacturerNameFacet">
      Alcatel (2)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="apple">
      Apple (13)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="blackberry">
      Blackberry (1)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="emporia">
      Emporia (1)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="huawei">
      Huawei (3)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="htc">
      HTC (6)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="lg">
      LG (7)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="samsung">
      Samsung (17)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="nokia">
      Nokia (1)
    </div>
    <div class="product" data-filter="google">
      Google (1)
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the image model -> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICfVW.jpg)

P.S: Sorry, but I'm really a novice at Hybris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to backoffice. Find Indexed Type menu and select your site index. Go to Indexed Properties and change facet state as true. Then run solr index update in Facet Search Config.

OOTB electronic store demo has brand facet option. You can check electronic storefront codes for details.

OOTB facet selector already getting count. Don't need to write static brand list. Hybris use component driven UI. You can check RefinementFacetComponent component for facet.

Comment: I think I have to add this field `private static final String MANUFACTURER_NAME = "manufacturerName";` to Controller and then populate and after that to invoke in .jsp file. Am I right?

btw where can I find this "RefinementFacetComponent component for facet"?

Comment: 6.3 already has manufacturerName. Which version do you use? You need to extend data objects (xml config) and it is populator for adding new attributes.

Comment: I'm using 6.2. In ProductData exist already `private String manufacturer;`

Comment: You can extend ProductData and creating populator for new attributes with following hybris development guidelines.

Comment: You mean to create reverse populator, because I have to fill data in model from DTOs. correct?